# d3 v5 axis transition

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have a graph in d3 v5, that displays part of a data set at a time and updates it on button presses. The graph content (lines, polygons, circles, images and text) transition just fine, but I can't figure out how to transition axes in d3 v5.

I have tried to follow this tutorial :
https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/678935d06d4601c25cb141bacd4068ce

Sadly, it uses d3 v4. I tried to use that syntax for my project, but it seems impossible to use call on a transition in d3 v5.

The problem is this part :

```
svg.select(".x")
  .transition()
    .call(x_axis);
```

I get this error :

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Axis<number | { valueOf(): number; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(transition: Transition<BaseType, { x: Date; y: number; doubt: number; }[][], HTMLElement, any>, ...'.
Types of parameters 'context' and 'transition' are incompatible.
```

It goes on a bit, basically it says that the axisBottom function should be applied to a selection and not to a transition.

I have looked around, but everything I find either uses d3 v4 or doesn't mention axis transitions. So : is it possible to transition axes in d3 v5, and if so how ?

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well? . Would be easier to help you out.

Comment: From the error it looks your problem isn't `d3 v4` to `d3 v5` but rather d3 JavaScript to d3 TypeScript.  You should add a `typescript` tag...

Comment: @Mark : You are right, I absolutely overlooked that possibility. I have looked into it and it seems that all I needed was to bind this to the axis function when calling it. I will answer the question and try to broaden my perspective for future problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark, I realized that I was looking at the problem from the wrong perspective. It didn't come from d3 but from Typescript. The axisBottom variable is a function, and Typescript requires it to have a context when used as a callback. Binding this solves that problem, as in :

```
svg.select(".x")
  .transition()
    .call(x_axis.bind(this));
```